# Efficient way of running lots of Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, dynamic-sql

**Summary**

Is there an efficient way to run large numbers of Dynamic SQL (on SQL Server 2005)?

**Details**

Our system allows users to create "email alert" subscriptions - where new matches on the system are emailed to them on a daily basis.

The subscription allows for multiple options, including the use of search keywords. A parser written by myself outputs the appropriate SQL code, taking into account `and`, `or` and brackets `()`. *The parser will not allow anything through that could be used for SQL Injection.*

For example, the keywords might be entered by the user as `this (that or other)` and the resultant query would end up roughly as...

```
SELECT *
FROM [VW_EMAIL_ALERT]
WHERE ([SEARCH] LIKE '%this%' AND ([SEARCH] LIKE '%that%' OR [SEARCH] LIKE '%other%'))
```

Each night, all those subscriptions are processed individually, because each one is potentially unique.  The result is that the batch processing has to run a cursor over every subscription and run the SQL through `sp_executesql`.

Obviously this is highly inefficient, and can cause serious overloading - leading in some cases to timeouts.  The stored-procedure that runs this processing is coded to split the subscriptions into blocks, so they're not all being called at once.

**Is there a better/more efficient way to do this?**

*Note: Unfortunately we are currently stuck supporting a minimum of SQL Server 2005, as some of our clients still use that technology*

Comment: Maybe a silly question but cannot you change it to use static SQL? (yeah I know that can take a lot of effort to change your schema). Btw are you using "pure" dynamic or parametric dynamic?

Comment: You do know that % is not a wildcard with a =?  As written that where can never be true.

Comment: This may be of some assistance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259850/dynamic-sql-and-stored-procedure-optimization

Comment: Thanks @Blam, sorry - that was just me writing an example for the question - you are completely correct... I will edit

Comment: There's nothing wrong performance-wise with parameterized dynamic sql (using sp_executesql). You can speed things up by paralelizing as much of the work as possible.

Comment: @jean - I'm not sure how I can use static SQL, when the whole point of this is that the query can contain potentially ANY query, as the user can enter any word(s) they want into the search terms

Comment: @dean - the majority of the the query is using parameters, but the problem is the entering of search terms

Comment: We need a lot more analysis to give sensible advice. Voting to close - let's move that over to dba.stackexchange.com, where the dba's will gladly spend some quality advice on this. I fear most developers here are not really in the "I know how sql works, really" category.

Comment: Free form searches can be parameterized as well. But the query sample in your post is inefficient, static or dynamic: for one it's the wildcards that kill SARGs, then the use of OR. Don't know what your real schema is, but you'd probably benefit from heavy denormalizing and preprocessing, and covering indexes for the most frequent cases. Try to divide the work in as much paralel jobs as possible. Hard to tell more without the complete picture.

Comment: If all your "dynamic" is just for searching any term in a (possible) collection on columns from some predefined tables You can turn that query in a static query for sure. All you need is to create a "table of terms" populate it (maybe depending on some flags) and search static over that terms (and maybe addressing from what tables and columns that term comes). The drawn back is it ill require a lot of development effort as I said in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for keywords that is the least efficient way you could do it
A like '%anything does not use an  index

Use a FullText search to index the words

Or write you own parser to index the unique words
You would build up a keywords table
And index the keyword
This is a very efficient query

```
select id 
  from keywords 
 where keyword = 'this' 
intersect 
select id 
  from keywords 
 where keyword in ( 'that','other')
```

Even with wildcards in the keywords it is still much more efficient than searching the entire text

Comment: Thanks Blam, I think you're right, a FullText search would be ideal for this situation - unfortunately we don't have FullText available on all our client servers.

Comment: Then write your own.  Just parse the text into a keywords table.

Comment: That's not a bad idea @Blam, I really like that :-)  Thank you!  (Edit: ah, but unfortunately it would not cope with `and`, `or` or brackets. Damn)

Comment: Why not?  I gave you a sample of and or.

Comment: True, but say (to take it to a bit of an extreme), the user decided to enter something like `this and (that or (other and something)) and else` then how could that be done?

Comment: 2 steps, first keywords, then again the current comparison AFTER the keywords lookup - that handles most fast then spends time to validate the results.

Comment: It works. I answered the stated question. It is still SQL.  Lets take it to and extreme where you expect me to answer multiple questions without even the courtesy of a +1.

Comment: Sorry @Blam, despite my question, I didn't expect you to create a query that could do it - I was just giving you an example of what *could* be entered by a user, and therefore it would need to be a lot more complex than the answer you have provided. However, you are right, you do deserve a +1

Comment: It is still SQL.  You really think there is stuff you can do in single table that you cannot do in a normalized keyword table?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. I'm currently looking into the viability of getting full-text search installed onto all our client server, as I'm not sure I could write something that could easily take any arbitrary text provided by a user and turn it into the correct SQL to use a keyword table.  It would be much easier and faster to allow users to enter text that can simply be passed to `CONTAINS`

Comment: Yes it would be easier but you said you could not install full text.  Just because you cannot easily write the query to a keyword table does not mean it cannot be done.  A keyword table is the most efficient design for a keyword search.  The stated question was efficient way.

Comment: (Helps if you tag my username, otherwise I don't get notifications, as somebody else joined the conversation.)  I said our clients don't have it, doesn't mean they can't install it though.  I think this conversation has run it's course... you've been a lot of help, thank you  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help. At my work, we replaced cursor with this kind of implementation.

```
DECLARE
    @strSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    Result_Query VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO
    #tmp
SELECT
    'SELECT * FROM [VW_EMAIL_ALERT] WHERE ([SEARCH] = ''%this%'' AND ([SEARCH] = ''%that%'' OR [SEARCH] = ''%other%''))'

UNION

SELECT
    'SELECT * FROM [VW_EMAIL_ALERT] WHERE ([SEARCH] = ''%this1%'' AND ([SEARCH] = ''%that1%'' OR [SEARCH] = ''%other1%''))'

SELECT
    @strSQL = @strSQL + Result_Query + ';'
FROM
    #tmp

SET
    @strSQL = LEFT(@strSQL, LEN(@strSQL) - 1)

PRINT @strSQL
EXEC(@strSQL)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I honestly can't see how that would be more efficient in the slightest.